# generating sitemap in django

Tags: django, sitemap

I have a website consist of many models and views already and over 25000 sub-urls.
I need to create a sitemap but it is not easy to use django-sitemaps frameworks because we need to add each model.

Is there any easy way to create a sitemap for Django web-sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a crawler ([scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)) to index your site, but tbh even with a lot of models it shouldn't be too hard to create a sitemap, have you run into any issues?

Comment: no i created a sitemao, but it is quite hard for too many models

Comment: [Google Says Don't Crawl Your Site To Build A Sitemap File](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-dont-crawl-your-site-sitemap-file-28453.html)

Answer (score 1):

Django sitemaps and wagtail sitemaps  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/sitemaps.html
does that. It processes all of your models. You can customize the sitemap class s well as the template. I use a docker container and customize the template and the code to for specific needs.

When I add a new blog, it automatically generates the entry.

https://www.fraydit.com/blogs/wagtail-sitemap-in-docker/

Here is an example of an implementation and customizing that module.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a framework or a library in Django which automatically generate sitemap without manually adding entry in the model then you can definitely use [jsl-django-sitemap](https://pypi.org/project/jsl-django-sitemap/) library.

**Salient features of this library:**

- No manual entry required for sitemap url
- include or exclude specific or all Django apps and their URLs in sitemap
- can exclude specific URLs matching regex. For example you don't want your APIs to be crawled then you can create a regex to exclude these URLs from sitemap
- This library is a wrapper o top of django sitemap

**Reference links**

- [Website Link](https://www.jsoftwarelabs.com/jslutils/django-sitemap-generator)
- [Pypi Package](https://pypi.org/project/jsl-django-sitemap/)
- [GitHub page](https://github.com/JSoftwareLabs/jsl_django_sitemap)

Credits: I have developed this library.